# Apache - two vhost conf files for same ServerName?

Tags: apache

I have a PHP web app served by Apache on a vhost.

I've just created an API in Scala, and would like to deploy Apache vhost config for it without touching the vhost config of the PHP web app.

The PHP app is at `www.mydomain.com` and the API will be served at `www.mydomain.com/api` (same domain/subdomain, allowing cookies to be shared)

I'm trying to treat the Apache config for each as separate concerns, although they both share the same `ServerName`.

Is it possible to get Apache to accept two `.conf` files that, combined, form the definition of a vhost for a domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [Include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include) directive which allows to *include* other files to achieve what you want.

One line like the next in your vhost blocks should work.

```
Include /etc/httpd/common_setings.conf
```